# Custom view by code like this

Tags: android, loops, android-custom-view

Hello I want to add custom view by code and make it go down in scroll view (the scroll view is by xml but I want the costum view to be automatic by Java code) create by loop and I don't know how to do that:

[image: a busy cat]

Thanks for helping Asaf.

Comment: Nice straight lines and good pictorial view :)

Comment: I think `GridView` should make a trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `LinearLayout` wrapper with vertical orientation programatically or through xml so in your code, i guess you should have a loop (`for.while`,etc) there you can instance your custom views and add it to your `LinearLayour` with:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout();

for(something)
{
CustomView custom = new CustomView();
// changes to yours custom view

layout.addView(custom);
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Or you can use a listview with a custom adapter ;)

Comment: hey this is not working to me its mark the CustimView in red and say:"Cannot resolve symbol 'CustomView' "

Comment: With customview you need replace it with another view as a imageview or a gallery o what you need instead

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are looking for : [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: I know how to do it with GridView I need to do it with costumview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ListView, and create a custom ArrayAdapter for it.  [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a good tutorial.  [Here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) is another one that helped me.